# Function pointer with undefined parameter count as template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I'm serching for a way to pass a function pointer with undefined parameter count and type as template argument.

In my research I've already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198044/function-pointer-as-template-argument)

```
STC<void (*)()> s(foo2, fp); // like this
```

So it seems like it is possible to pass function pointers as template parameter in general. My question would now be if it is possible to do something like this

```
STC<void (*)(T&&... t)> s(foo2, fp);
```

Additional information:
The class which I would like to pass the function pointer should only hold a list of functions in an array and has no further functions.

Comment: Impossible. You can't have a pointer to a template, only to an instantiation of a template.

Comment: You should try `std::function` with a variadic template parameter pack and _perfect forwarding _ maybe.

Comment: @user9212993 impossible.

Comment: Variable arguments are messy and not type safe. Why not take a std::vector reference as a parameter?  Then you could call the function like `s({foo2, fp});`.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what your hypotetical syntax means. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for partial specialization.

I mean something like (thanks to Jarod42 for the improvement)

```
template <typename>
struct foo;

template <typename ... Ts>
struct foo<void(*)(Ts ...)>
 { void(*ptr)(Ts ...); };
```

But observe that the template parameter isn't a function pointer; is the type of a function pointer.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename>
struct foo;

template <typename ... Ts>
struct foo<void(*)(Ts ...)>
 { void(*ptr)(Ts ...); };

void func1 ()
 { std::cout << "func1" << std::endl; }

void func2 (int, long)
 { std::cout << "func2" << std::endl; }


int main ()
 {
   foo<decltype(&func1)>  f1 { &func1 };
   foo<decltype(&func2)>  f2 { &func2 };

   f1.ptr();
   f2.ptr(1, 2L);
 }
```

Comment: `void(*)(Ts && ...)` should probably be `void(*)(Ts...)` as there are no forwarding references here.

Comment: @Jarod42 - You are right. I remained too adherent to the example of the OP. Thanks.